# LINQ to Objects - Reduce repetition - Map inside select statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using LINQ to objects to run the multiple queries like below, **I want to retain a separate method for each of the queries** below but I want to have a function to map inside the select statement.

1. GetDTOCourseListActiveCourses
2. GetDTOCourseListWithValidDates
3. GetDTOCourseListRequirePayments

With each I am currently doing a manual mapping exercise inside the select for each query like below:

```
    public IList<DTOCourse> GetDTOCourseListActiveCourses()
    {
        var query = _UoW.tblcoursRepo.All.Where(c => c.IsActive == true);

        IList<DTOCourse> courselist = new List<DTOCourse>();

        courselist = query.Select(x => new DTOCourse
        {
        ////// BUT, I want to create a function here to do the mapping //
        courseId = x.CourseID,
        courseTitle = x.CourseTitle,
        mainHeading = x.MainHeading.description,
        courseType = x.ListType.description,
        courseStatus = x.ListStatus.description,
        orgId = x.OrgID.Value
        }).ToList();

        return courselist;
    }
```

I have created the following method to map to the DTO class, this works fine when converting a single instance:

```
    public DTOCourse MaptblcourseToDTOCourse(tblcours course)
    {

        DTOCourse dto = new DTOCourse
        {
            courseId = course.CourseID,
            courseTitle = course.CourseTitle,
            mainHeading = course.MainHeading.description,
            courseType = course.ListType.description,
            courseStatus = course.ListStatus.description,
            orgId = course.OrgID.Value
        };

        return dto;
    }
```

How can I combine this method to map within a select? I'm looking for something like below:

```
    public IList<DTOCourse> GetDTOCourseListActiveCourses()
    {
        var query = _UoW.tblcoursRepo.All.Where(c => c.IsActive == true);

        IList<DTOCourse> courselist = new List<DTOCourse>();

        courselist = query.Select(x => new DTOCourse
        {
            MaptblcoursToDTOCourse(x)
        }).ToList();

        return courselist;
    }
```

Comment: Simple: `var courseList = query.Select(MaptblcoursToDTOCourse);`

Comment: If that's LINQ to Objects, those are extremely inefficient queries. You don't show what `_UoW.tblcoursRepo.All` is, but that really really should be an `IQueryable<T>` if not a `DbSet<T>`

Comment: So what is the issue? And why `entity-framework` tag? If you really are using LINQ to Objects, there should not be any issue and tag is not needed, do you mean LINQ to **Entities** instead?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks, yeah these are IQueryable, queries are more complex, just shortened for brevity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You can call your mapping method in your `Select` call like this:

```
courselist = query.Select(x => MaptblcoursToDTOCourse(x)).ToList();
```

Or even shorter:

```
courselist = query.Select(MaptblcoursToDTOCourse).ToList();
```